# The Server could not complete your request

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I've seen several other forum entries for this issue in SharePoint Designer 2013 when accessing my SharePoint sites. It will pop up the message `The server could not complete your request. For more specific information, click the Details button.` repeatedly until I force to kill the SPDESIGN.EXE from the Task Manager. The message  is very vague and does NOT tell you what is the root of error.

When you click Details button, it does NOT any information as well.

The solution on other sites is to enable anonymous authentication on the Sharepoint Web Services site. I've done that on my web app, as well as the SharePoint web services app, with the same error message. I've tried doing an `IIS reset`, as well as following the instructions on [this](http://akavitgroup.com/blog/sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-2013-server-could-not-complete-your-request-error-and-fix) link. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you enabled `Anonymous Authentication`, `Asp.net Impersonation`, `Forms Authentication` and `Windows authentication` for `SharePoint Webservices` using `inetmgr`?

Comment: yes, I have. I still get the same error

Comment: Can you check the SharePoint server and see any error in `EventVwr` or `ULS Logs`?

Comment: there are a bunch of errors in ULS Logs, but I don't know which ones relate to the sharepoint designer connection - some with `owstimer.exe`, some with `v3wp.exe`, and some with `mssearch.exe`

Comment: Try connecting using SPD and keep and eye of the logs. Like connect at 4:00 and get all log event from 4:00 and look for errors. Also any error in the event logs?

Comment: Does anyone have an update on this?